# SQL Server Select column based on where query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

Can I select a column based on a where clause? I have a table in SQL Server 2012 that has a salesperson code, and all twelve months in number format (01=January, 02=February, 03=March, etc.). The rows are dollar amounts for sales figures.

I want to be able to select a row from a certain month and salesperson code. My logic is basically Select Amount from Table Where Column = 07 and Code = 100.

So basically in the below table, how would I select the row for March and salesperson code 200 (which is 10006).

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+-------------+
| SalesPersonCode  | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | Jun | and so on...|
+-----------------------------------+------------+-------------+
| 100              |50003|13232|66565|65656|96656|     ...     |
| 200              |65653|43432|10006|65236|23236|     ...     |
| 300              |32131|43432|44343|56563|21212|     ...     |
+-----------------------------------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please post your table schema and clarify what it is you are trying to do. I don't understand. Are you trying to dynamically define the column to search, or are you trying to search multiple columns?

Comment: Sorry - I added a basic table schema.  I am trying to dynamically define the column to search.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question, you have a table with a `salescode` column and 12 additional columns, one for each month and each stores an `amount` you want to display by passing in a parameter?

If so, here's one option using a `case` statement for each month:

```
select salescode, 
       case when @column = 1 then month1
            when @column = 2 then month2
            ...
            when @column = 12 then month12
       end as amount
from yourtable
where salescode = @salescode
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to have different table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Sales(
SalesPersonCode INT,
Period SMALLINT,
Value INT
)
GO
```

To get the table values as you showed would require Pivoting the data, but for everything else it will be much easier/faster to extract. Like this:

```
SELECT Value FROM tbl_Sales
WHERE SalesPersonCode = 100 and Period = 1607;
```

Comment: I think the OP intended `Column = 07` to mean "Search the seventh column", not match against a specific column named `Column`. If it was so simple, the OP would just be able to run that query.

Comment: @Robert Columbia Your crystal ball is better then mine because I do not have any.

Comment: Sorry guys - I clarified the question. I couldn't figure out how to add the table schema until right now.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the table format the same? It is easier to visually view the data when we view the data as a whole.

Comment: How many years of data do you plan to keep? Only one? If you have that kind kind of requirement, then you can use your format. Just be smarter.

Comment: Yes. I just want to keep one year of data. How would I select a certain month and salesperson code?

Comment: If you still want to have 12 months as columns then you can use query from @sgeddes